# Using jQuery, or JavaScript, to make an image active during an on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I've found a function to make a button work correctly using jQuery to change the selector to active. I am however having issues having an image with an overlay go into an active state with a click.

For the HTML I have:

```
<div class="img-container1 image-container" image-var="image1.jpg">
      <%= image_tag('image1.jpg') %>
      <div class="wk-after">
        <div class="centered-wk">
          <span class="fa fa-check-circle check-circle"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="centered-wk wk-select">
          SELECTED
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

In CSS I have:

```
.img-container1{
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 position: relative;
}
.image-container:hover .wk-after, .image-container.active .wk-after{
display: block;
background: rgba(231, 68, 129, 0.75);
}

.wk-after{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.image-container.active .wk-after {
display: block;
background: rgba(231, 68, 129, 0.75);
}

.image-container .wk-after {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
font-size: 16px;
display: none;
color: #FFF;}

.centered-wk {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
align-self: center;
align-items: center;}
```

I've attempted to use the following jQuery to grab the class and make the change:

```
$('.img-container1').click(function(){
      console.log('test');
      $('.image-container').removeClass('active');
      $(this).parents('.image-container').addClass('active');
      console.log($(this).closest('.image-container'));
        });
```

But it doesn't work. I put in the console log to see if it's actually hitting the container and nothing. If I change it to say a button I have on the page the log appears. If I manually type into the console in the webpage it actually appears.

Should I be using JavaScript instead? What would be the best way to get by a class name add an on click and apply active class?

**EDIT**: this code works when I type it directly into the web browser console:

```
var $link = $('.img-container1');
    $link.click(function(){
      $link.removeClass('active');
      console.log("testing");
      $(this).addClass('active');
```

So the bigger question is how can I get this actually work when I load the page?

Comment: directly `$(this).addClass('active');` the classes for the same element so no need to use `parents()` or `closest()` ..

Comment: You want to make it active when you click once and you want to make it inactive when you click again?

Comment: Take a look at .toggleClass() (http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code works in console, probably you add event listeners before dom fully loaded. Try ready() function or add your script in bottom of page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.img-container').click(function(){   
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
          });    
    });
```

[toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/qn1v8kpn/)

Comment: What I posted, and this, actually resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
  $('.img-container1').click(function(){
    var isActive = $(this).hasClass('active');

    $('.img-container1').removeClass('active');

    if(isActive == false){

      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
```

Comment: Why not to use toggleClass() instead?

Comment: toggleClass can be used if its only one class in question. I am not sure if it can be used when multiple classes are defined for an element.

Comment: This will actually keep active on multiple images but only works when typing into the browser console for some reason.

Comment: Oh if you are using class selector than this code applies to all the element with this same class. You should use the id instead.

Comment: @muasif80 "applies to all the element"? you mean bind click to all `.img-container1`? you used `$(this)` so it will not applies to all

Comment: I have updated the code a little. Can you please see has it solved the issue? @Jake

Comment: This does work for the page. The problem is looking like it's a bigger issue in that the code ONLY works if it's put directly into the web page.

Comment: @jake maybe cache problem, put this code in your main js file and press `F5` or disable cache by console dev

Comment: Where are you putting the code right now? Do you have this at some live url? O can you put this on jsfiddle?

Comment: It's actually built in Ruby on Rails web application through a CMS so it's not super possible to put it all in a jsfiddle. So it makes it super difficult to share the issue.

Comment: You can see at this url it is selecting the image successfully on one click and on the next click it is deselecting it. https://jsfiddle.net/muasif80/e43vdrkq/1/ If it is not providing solution to your problem, then i am afraid more info is needed to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So here was the actual solution:

```
var $link = $('.img-container1');
$('.img-group').on("click", '.img-container1', function(){
$link.removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Apparently I needed to bind the img-container1 to the parent class and it worked.